# 'UserCreationForm' object has no attribute 'FormWrapper' in Django

Tags: python, django

## this is my views.py

why i am facing this problem wether oldform is FormWrapper has been removed from the new Django version.

```
 from django.shortcuts import render
 from django.http import HttpResponse
 from books.models import Author
from models import ContactForm 
from django.db.models import Q
#from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from django.template.engine import (
                         _context_instance_undefined,                     _dictionary_undefined, _dirs_undefined,
                           )
#from django oldforms as forms
 from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreatForm

def register(request):
  form = UserCreationForm()
   if request.method == 'POST':
       data = request.POST.copy()
       errors = form.get_validation_errors(data)
       if not errors:
          new_user = form.save(data)
          return HttpResponseRedirect("/books/")
   else:
       data, errors = {}, {}
   return render_to_response("registration/register.html", {
         'form' : form.FormWrapper(form, data, errors)
          })
```

Comment: Where is your views.py? Please explain your issue clearly and also do proper format so its more readable.

Comment: this is my views.py mr.

Answer (score 0):

Yikes - that is some ugly code. You've really answered your own question - that import is failing because the class isn't there anymore.

Why not just:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render


def register(request):
    form = UserCreationForm(data=request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('name-of-books-url'))
    return render(request, 'registration/register.html', {'form': form}
```